# Edit DataGridView in Winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to implement a datagridview with both bound and unbound columns . For bound columns i just used typed dataset (xsd). How to turn my unbound column into editable and save the changes back to database . I'm a beginner can anyone tell me a good  one .

Comment: There is no question mark in your question. What are you asking exactly?

Comment: Here's is exactly what i'm looking ,  I want to fetch the unbound column value which was entered manually by the user , and insert them on another table ...

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of tutorials

How to create [unbound](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial) columns

This [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/d94cf29d-12bb-4f17-9426-2faac40d4c2f/) will explain more about saving unbound columns to the DB

This [zip](http://www.timvw.be/2007/04/05/datagridview-to-excel/) will show you how to save unbound columns to the DB